# What unity version should I install from the list?

Tags: unity

[image: Unity installation versions]

The problem is that all my projects are in unity editor 2019 version and if I switch to a newer version I'm afraid it will start asking me for api changes and other changes that it will make to my projects. What version should I install so it will not change too much my projects and will not damage them ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to answer this question as written, as we have no idea what APIs you're using, and what's changed in the different versions of Unity.

I recommend making a backup of your projects, then get the latest version of Unity listed for LTS (Long Term Support... these versions get 2 years of fixes and updates, meaning you can get updates to that version without breaking your project).

Let this version convert your projects, and see what doesn't work. Unity is generally pretty good at doing these upgrades without breaking things, though their auto-script fixes may not be the most efficient code possible.

If something is broken beyond your ability (or will) to fix, then revert to your backed up copy and stick with the version of Unity it was made with.